# Google Apps Script personal script won't authorize

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-authentication

I have previously had Google Apps Script using the `UrlFetchApp` no problem.

Yesterday I've created a new one and I can't run any functions whatsoever if I include the `UrlFetchApp` service - even if it's commented out!

When I try to run the script I get the usual "permissions" popup. But when I give my consent I get:

> Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
> This app has not yet been verified by Google in order to use Google Sign in.

---

This is personal script and Im the only person who will be using it - what are my options? I am not going to go and obtain a domain just to go through verification just to run a small simple script...

Comment: Create a new project?

Comment: Can you be more specific? This IS a new apps script project.

Comment: So you cannot include `UrlFetchApp` at all? And it works correctly if this is not included? You get this same behaviour for any new project you create?

Comment: Make a new project and try again. When Google says **this app**, it means this project.

Comment: @TheMaster I created 2 and the all behave the same

Comment: @Iamblichus Exactly, specifically, if I don't include any mentions of UrlFetchApp the function works fine. If I include it but comment it out, it doesn't work without me supplying authorization, which the app won't let me do.

Comment: *When I try to run the scrip* 1.How are you trying to run the script? From menu or from script editor? 2. Do you have another  Google account to try?

Comment: @TheMaster Script editor - play button. I have not tried it with another account but I will try.

Comment: @themaster I tried doing it on another account and it seems to work IF I sign out of all other account, as the editor doesn't appear to let me change the user. When I switched back to my original account, creating new script that use the UrlFetchApp still won't work.

Comment: Seems your account hit some limits. Create a issue in issue tracker (see tag info [tag:google-apps-script] for link) and [edit] the created issue in your question for wider audience.

Comment: Do not know if that's still relevant for you, @SergeiTrunov, but in case anyone else encounters this problem - have you checked the consent screen in the GCP project (not the apps script one) - sounds awfully familiar to a reaching the limit on number of users with unverified consent screen (which would explain the "This app has not yet been verified")

Comment: @OlegValter It's definately related to the GCP  project - when you create a new project there is a default GCP project that Google doesn't really tell you about anywhere. This has  exhausted my logins or something of that sort. I do have a separate GCP project and once I've change my GAS to this GCP project in the 'Resources' tabs this has resolved my issue!

Comment: @SergeiTrunov - actually, they do [tell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#default_cloud_platform_projects) :) You seem to have hit a very broad issue that is more than a year old and still unresolved. Most of the time it is resolved by changing the project (ironically, a client of mine got stuck in this issue recently - this is why I am walking through the questions submittied - and the horror of the situation is that they can't change the GCP for some reason).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450