# Issue with Google sign in and scopes while developing spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a spreadsheet script for a game I play.

Its been 3 weeks I'm working on it and everything was running smoothly and ran all my tests and verification successfully. Then yesterday when I wake up
I started to get this message when trying to run the functions I've created:
[image]

When I read trough the docs here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en
It says I don't need verification while building an app.

If someone as an idea and/or a link i can refer to about this kind of issues when building scripts(not use other people ones) or explain me whats causing my issue it would be greatly appreciated.

[ edit:
I've found where/what was the issue but I really dont understand it.
Here's the code that activated "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui" Oauth scope:

```
function loadAxieIventory() {
 //show head off
 showHead = false;
//axie template
 axieTemp_ = axieTemp3_; //(change the value of the function in the actual function)
//get axie inventory with 
//parts inventory
};
```

I really don't understand whats different with this function from my other function so that it activate an other scope. 
Also the function is not finish yet and pretty much does nothing at this stage.
]

Regards Guillaume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to run simple Google Script: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/trying-to-run-simple-google-script-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [Google Apps Script unauthorizable](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820)

Google does seem to know about this issue but if it's causing problems you can file your own bug about it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).

You can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.