# Google Apps Script not verified ( without advanced option)

Tags: google-apps-script

Things fare fine for the first two days.

I do not remember doing anything special to my account, but suddenly all of the app script (either bound script or standalone one) is disabled because it "has not been verified yet by Google".

And the scripts I have been trying to run are just some simple ones like getName() or getData().

Anyone can help? I can not continue the course unless this issue can be solved.

Much appreciated for the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to run simple Google Script: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/trying-to-run-simple-google-script-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for)

Comment: I would recommend you to post that you are also having the issue in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820) as @theMaster suggested in his other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/trying-to-run-simple-google-script-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for)