# How can I bypass "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" in a Google Sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to use a script in a google sheet I've used in the past, and suddenly while trying to make a new sheet with this code, I'm getting a new error that is seemingly impossible to bypass.

["Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqMya.png)

*Normally*, or at least every time I have used this script in the past, there has been an "advanced" and "continue anyway" option.

["This app isn't verified yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90PTT.png)

["Advanced > Continue to Untitled Project (Unsafe)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okeir.png)

This is the code.gs script [[gitlab link]](https://gitlab.com/jeffers.david93/wayfarer/blob/master/Code.gs), how can I bypass this saftey check, and continue using this script as needed?

And for reference, [these are the instructions for the whole project on git lab,](https://gitlab.com/jeffers.david93/wayfarer/tree/master#b-if-you-want-to-create-your-own-sheet-you-should-follow-these-instructions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to run simple Google Script: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/trying-to-run-simple-google-script-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for)

Comment: It seems to be the same issue, but there are not any solutions there either.

Comment: There is no solution currently. You or we could do nothing except requesting Google to fix it: Star the issue.

Comment: I get very frustrated when GAS tries to protect me from running scripts I just wrote on my own account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct solution for the issue you are encountering.

According to the issue from [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820), the error you are encountering may be due to this cause:

- an external user runs the script with sensitive scopes

A possible solution:

- run the script from **Incognito Mode** and **remove** the project's permissions from `myaccount.google.com/permissions`

Ultimately, if this still doesn't solve your issue you can **star** the issue on `Issue Tracker` [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820).

Comment: Thanks! I've went ahead and starred the issue, and it looks like the "Temporary" was really temporary after all, because now it's working.