# How to fix "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" screen on an unpublished bound script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I made a new google sheet with a simple script that does an external call with UrlFetchApp.

However, when I try to run or test the code, it says authorization required. App needs permission. I then click on review permissions, followed by clicking on my Gmail account.

> **Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app**
>
> This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Any advice on how to resolve this? Why is this showing up for my own unpublished unfinished code?

Comment: make sure you're browser is not signed into a different google account, if it is open your script in a guest browser window

Comment: What runtime are you using? What web browser are you using? Are signed in into multiple accounts? Have you already tried to on incognito/private/safe modes?

Answer (score 1):

**Reasons**

Making external calls is a sensitive scope. If by any chance you tried to authorize from *any* (reauthorizations count as well) account 100 times (see [user cap help page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162)) *throughout* the development process, you will not be able to proceed.

That is usually the primary reason for this screen, but sometimes you get locked even if the project is new (for example, for some G Suite accounts). If that happens, in my experience *the only* way to fix it is by going through the review.

There is also a [thread on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820) if cannot resolve it with methods listed below.

Finally, take a look at related Q&As:

["Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" error when trying to authorize a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app-error-when-trying-to-aut/63063149#63063149)

[How can I bypass "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" in a Google Sheets script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672745/how-can-i-bypass-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app-in-a-go?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**How to fix**

1. [Switch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) the Google Cloud Platform Project to a new standard one. This will reset the counter.
2. Create a new bound script from a new Google Sheets spreadsheet (this works the same as switching GCP, as a default cloud project is assigned to the script project).
3. Go through the [OAuth verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) process. Don't worry, it is not that long and only requires a video of how you use the scopes.