# "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled" error when trying to authorize a script project I am the owner of

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

Since March, I have been developing a clutch of custom Apps Script functions to augment a spreadsheet.  Yesterday, I tried to add a new backup function (based on one on GitHub) to one version of the Spreadsheet. And now, that spreadsheet cannot run *any* functions.

When I try to run a function, I now get  popup:

> "Authorization Required -- a script attached to this document needs your permission to run".

When I click "Continue", I am asked to "Choose an account". I am offered a list of one account -- my own one.  This is also the one mentioned in the "Developer info" when I click for details of the script to be authorized.  So I am being asked to authorize my own script to access my account

BUT when I click that account, I get a popup with a red exclamation mark sign and

> "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app. This app has not been verified yet by google in order to use Google Sign In".

No buttons or options, just that text.

Again: this worked until yesterday -- until I tried to write the backup file.  So what happens now?  What "app" is it talking about?  How long is "temporarily"?  Nothing has been verified by google because I am still writing the code!  I'm just trying to debug it in my own spreadsheet!

So what can I do?

Comment: Which kind of App are you talking about? Do you have an Addon, a Web App, a script bound to a spreadsheet? An alone standing script that you manually run from the Apps Script editor? Or on trigger? Providing your code and more eplanation would help troubleshooting. Mind that the account you choose to run the function should be the same like the owner of the spreadsheet and script (unless modified by permissions).

Comment: It's a script bound to a spreadsheet, run either from a menu entry in the spreadsheet or from its onEdit hook.

I believe my account is the only one in play: I own the sheet, I wrote the script, and I'm trying to use it...

Comment: I am wondering if the function attached to the button calls some other function or even a WebApp from an external developer. Can you show your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to run simple Google Script: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/trying-to-run-simple-google-script-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for) --please, ignore the message, it is added automatically (let's link these scattered questions to the canonical one - the issue is still ongoing)

Answer (score 0):

The limit of sign-ins for unverified app is limited, every new sign-in(one scope change) by same user is counted as +1. So you probably hit that limit.

You can try 
1) Adding /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */ which will skip "unverified app" message. Of course this is only possible if script only access bound spreadsheet data, no other sensitive scopes.

2) Cloning the spreadsheet/script to reset quota.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @roma

I can't do "OnlyCurrentDoc" because I'm (now) trying to save a backup to a different file.

I have been working on it a lot, so I guess I could have hit a limit. 

BUT I've just tried cloning the sheet (with "File->Make A Copy" ), and the copy behaves exactly the same: when I click to run a function (one that DOESN'T touch any other document), I'm told I need to authorize, and when I select my account, I immediately get "Temporarily disabled".

So no joy.