# Previously unobserved "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

we have a problem with the authorization of the script in a google spreadsheet. Script downloads data from other ad platforms. After signing up we get alert:

> Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app. This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Until this time, there was no problem with authorization.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question (linking another Q&A with other solutions and possible issues)? ["Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" error when trying to authorize a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app-error-when-trying-to-aut)

Answer (score 0):

### This is a bug:

This is a known issue some users have been experiencing in the last few months. It was reported on Issue Tracker some time ago:

- [Google Apps Script unauthorizable](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820)

While this hasn't been fixed yet, Google's suggested workaround, explained in [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820#comment76), is to switch your default project to a standard GCP project, following these steps:

- [Switching to a different standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)

I'd suggest you to star the referenced issue in order to help prioritizing it.