# Unable to give access to Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am just learning how to use Google App Script for some dummy data in a Google Sheet and I keep running into "This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access."
Less Secure App is already ON, and I don't know what else to do. I'm just trying to run a darn SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreasheet(); and I can't even get through that. Please help, so frustrated with Google. Thank you.

Edit: I can't even run Google's own "your first script" tutorial because of this issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get this alert https://imgur.com/DWoqfKY.png when you click Run button? It's need to click Review permissions. Then will appear next alert, you need to select your account. Then сlick the tiny gray link 'Advanced'. Then the as well tiny gray 'Go to Name_of_your_project (unsafe)'. Then click on the big blue button 'Allow'. Did you do these steps?

Comment: https://howtogapps.com/google-script-authorization-review-and-accept-the-permission-guide/

Comment: As questions on this site should be self-contained, please add a [mcve] as well the steps that you followed to run your script.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Hi thanks for your reply and yes I did all of those steps. I have added screenshots of what I got. The last page with the error has nothing clickable.

Comment: @Rubén Hi, I have added screenshots of what I saw. Thank you

Comment: @Rubén Dear Lord... I did not know the problem was that bad... it seems so simple and dumb. How am I not even able to run their own Tutorial Code? Thank you for the even Ruben

Comment: This looks to be a more appropriate "canonical" thread for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59070450/1595451

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" error when trying to authorize a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app-error-when-trying-to-aut)